# @dynamic property accessors in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-runtime

So far I have seen only CoreData using `@dynamic` property accessor definitions. What other ways are there for a property to get dynamic accessors in Cocoa object so that they can be marked as `@dynamic`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, all declared properties are @dynamic, however you can declare them as @synthesize.
@dynamic means, that you will provide getter and setter implementation in your class, that may be linked to no any i-var.

Comment: I know what `@dynamic` means. I wanted to know what are other means without CoreData model to provide dynamic accessors for an object's property.

Comment: not sure got your request clearly, but one of the options is a facading property, that in getter & setter will work with other hidden properties

Answer (score 1):

You can generate an accessor at runtime by responding to `+resolveInstanceMethod:` (which is what Core Data does) or simulate it with `-forwardInvocation:`. I’ve seen this used in mock model objects which support arbitrary (object-valued) properties, although in that case properties were declared in unimplemented categories so no explicit `@dynamic` was used. (Actually, I’ve written [a stupid hack](http://jens.ayton.se/blag/fun-with-the-objc-runtime/) that makes `NSDictionary` behave this way.)

I could imagine a similar approach being used for a proxy object.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a property dynamic yourself. This may be useful if, for example, the getter and setter methods are implemented by your superclass.

Comment: What's the point of declaring accessors in superclass without declaring the property in the same class?